# How to group by a property of an object in a Java List?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of resource objects. Resource object is defined as:

```
class Resource {
    String ip;
    String subnet;
    // other properties...
}
```

I need a datastrucutre like a map where the key is a random resource in one subnet and value is a list of all resources in other subnets.

For example, if `S` denotes subnet and `R` denotes resource, the list has:

```
S1R1, S1R2, S2R1, S2R2, S3R1 and S3R2
```

Expected output is:

```
S1R1 -> S2R1, S2R2, S3R1, S3R2
S2R2 -> S1R1, S1R2, S3R1, S3R2
S3R1 -> S1R1, S1R2, S2R1, S2R2
```

I tried using stream and collect which grouped based on subnets, not sure how to proceed from here.

```
Map<String, Set<Resource>> grouped = resourceList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Resource::getSubnet, Collectors.toSet()));
```

Comment: Please explain more about the expected outcome.

Comment: Expected outcome is there should be a map or a similar structure where the key is any random resource in one subnet and value is a list of all resources in all other subnets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn’t work with the `groupingBy` collector, as it works by passing the elements belonging to a group to each group’s downstream collector and you can’t tell it to pass the others.

One way to achieve what you’ve described, is

```
TreeMap<Resource, Set<Resource>> map
                              = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(Resource::getSubnet));
for(Resource resource: resourceList)
    map.computeIfAbsent(resource, x -> new HashSet<>(resourceList)).remove(resource);

map.forEach((resource,set) -> System.out.println(resource+" -> "
    +set.stream().map(Resource::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))));
```

Which, given the list `S1R1, S1R2, S2R1, S2R2, S3R1, S3R2` will produce

```
S1R1 -> S3R2, S2R1, S2R2, S3R1
S2R1 -> S3R2, S1R2, S3R1, S1R1
S3R1 -> S1R2, S2R1, S2R2, S1R1
```

while the order of the `Set`’s elements is undefined, the `Map`’s keys actually are not picked randomly, it’s the first encountered resource of each subnet.

You could do this with two chained stream operations

```
Map<Resource, Set<Resource>> map = resourceList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Resource::getSubnet, Collectors.toSet()))
    .values().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        set -> set.iterator().next(),
        set -> {
            Set<Resource> other = new HashSet<>(resourceList);
            other.removeAll(set);
            return other;
        }));
```

Here, the resource picked from each group is indeed unspecified. Unlike the `TreeMap` based approach, you would have to know the actual `Resource` (or try them all) to lookup a group. The `TreeMap` allows to lookup a group by using any `Resource` from the same subnet.

Comment: wouldn't  `String.join(", ", set)` cause a compilation error or is there something I am missing here?

Comment: minor, but `list` in `Set<String> other = new HashSet<>(list);` is not declared anywhere.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dumb here, but what should `list` be declared as? An empty list?
Also, `other.removeAll(set)` is throwing an incompatible types error: `Collection cannot be applied to object`

Comment: Got it. Slightly modified the answer:
`
Collection<Set<Resource>> values = resourceList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Resource::getSubnet, Collectors.toSet())).values();
Map<Resource, HashSet<Resource>> set = values.stream().
                collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        set -> set.iterator().next(),
                        set -> {
                            HashSet<Resource> other = new HashSet<>(resourceList);
                            other.removeAll(set);
                            return other;
                        }
                ));
`

Comment: `Collection<Set<Resource>> values = resourceList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Resource::getSubnet, Collectors.toSet())).values();`

`Map<Resource, HashSet<Resource>> finalSet = values.stream().
                collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        set -> set.iterator().next(),
                        set -> {
                            final HashSet<Resource> other = new HashSet<>(resourceList);
                            other.removeAll(set);
                            return other;
                        }
              ));`

Comment: @Aominè there were some leftovers from my first test, which I did with just strings, so `list` should be `resourceList`, `String` should be `Resource`, and, yes, we can’t simply use `String.join` when the set’s element type is `Resource`. I fixed it; the printing code still assumes that `Resource.toString()` return `subnet+ip`, but that shouldn’t affect the program logic.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what how subnets work but you have to figure out the below relationship(*isSubNetOf*).

```
BiPredicate<Resource, Resource> isSubNetOf = (parent, subnet) -> ???;

Map<Resource, Set<Resource>> resourceToSubnets = resourceList.stream()
        .collect(toMap(
                Function.identity(),
                x -> resourceList.stream().filter(v -> isSubNetOf.test(x, v)).collect(toSet())
                ));
```

If you want a `Map<String, Set<Resource>>` change `Function.identity()` to the required `Resource::getIp` or `Resource::getSubnet`.